# How do I center my logo for mobile and move the hamburger menu to the far left?

Tags: shopify, center

I have a Shopify website and I'm trying to center my logo for mobile and move the hamburger menu to the far left for mobile as well, how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to go into the style-sheet and edit the CSS inside your media queries. You'll find your media queries in your styles.css.liquid file.

And here is link: [How to edit html/css of shopify](https://www.templatemonster.com/help/shopify-how-to-edit-htmlcss-files.html)